# Makefile and gcc importing sqlite3 not working

Tags: c, linux, sqlite, gcc, makefile

## Introduction

I am experiencing difficulties when using **gcc -l**.

I have a **Makefile** that either **compiles** my files or **execute** them on qemu. I decided to make a database that storages or reads the users credentials. The db reader file isn't in kernel.c file (programs main file) but in a seperated file called recive.c which afterwards is imported to the kernel.c file.

When running the database reader, recive.c, only by compiling that file using `gcc recive.c -l sqlite3` it works well but when I tried to pass that gcc command to my makefile it doesn't.

## Structure

Here it is my makefile structure:

## compiler

```
CC = /usr/bin/gcc
```

## linker

```
LD = /usr/bin/ld
```

## sources

```
SRC = src
```

## objects

```
OBJ = obj
```

## compiler flags

```
CC_FLAGS = $(INCLUDE) $(DEFINES) -m32 -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra
```

## Kernel Compilation

```
$(OBJ)/kernel.o : $(SRC)/kernel.c

    @printf "[ $(SRC)/kernel.c ]\n"
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -l sqlite3 -c $(SRC)/kernel.c -o $(OBJ)/kernel.o
    @printf "\n"
```

## What have I Tried

I tried to use the following commands in the makefile

- -l sqlite3
- -lsqlite3
- -L sqlite3
- gcc src/kernel.c -l sqlite3

## Error Information

I am using **Linux Mint**.
My terminal Output:

```
[ linking... ]
/usr/bin/ld -m elf_i386 -T ./config/linker.ld -nostdlib -o out/Terminal.bin obj/asm/entry.o obj/asm/load_gdt.o obj/asm/load_idt.o obj/asm/exception.o obj/asm/irq.o obj/io_ports.o obj/vga.o obj/string.o obj/console.o obj/gdt.o obj/idt.o obj/isr.o obj/8259_pic.o obj/keyboard.o obj/kernel.o
/usr/bin/ld: obj/kernel.o: na função "loginMain":
kernel.c:(.text+0x252): referência não definida para "sqlite3_open"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x26a): referência não definida para "sqlite3_errmsg"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x27d): referência não definida para "fprintf"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x28c): referência não definida para "sqlite3_close"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x2be): referência não definida para "sqlite3_exec"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x2d9): referência não definida para "fprintf"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x2ef): referência não definida para "fprintf"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x2fe): referência não definida para "sqlite3_free"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x30d): referência não definida para "sqlite3_close"
/usr/bin/ld: kernel.c:(.text+0x323): referência não definida para "sqlite3_close"
make: *** [Makefile:49: all] Erro 1
```

## Makefile file

You can find my makefile here: https://pastebin.com/XURDCtcW

Comment: I think it's the order of the arguments

Comment: `-l sqlite3 -c` doesn’t add up, does it? (Libraries are a thing of linker phase)

Comment: You need to show the the parts of the Makefile that do the linking. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: Please show a complete example Makefile as one single code block instead of a bunch of code snippets mixed with text and headings.

Comment: I think what @kirjosieppo was getting at was if you re-order the compilation line, it will affect the linking order. So `$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -l sqlite3 -c $(SRC)/kernel.c -o $(OBJ)/kernel.o` should be `$(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) -c $(SRC)/kernel.c -o $(OBJ)/kernel.o -lsqlite3`. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Xinthral I meant that `-c` indicates the linker isn’t run at all

Comment: Xinthral, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, well I attempted to make a sqlite program for fun but the relevant portion to this discussion is the make file, and notice that with the `LFLAGS` variable I utilized `-lsqlite3`:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wno-write-strings
LFLAGS = -lsqlite3
DBAPI = dbApi
EXECT = examiner
TESTR = xtest
UTILZ = utilities

all: $(DBAPI).o $(TESTR).o $(UTILZ).o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXECT).exe $^ $(LFLAGS)

$(DBAPI).o: $(DBAPI).h
$(TESTR).o: $(TESTR).h
$(UTILZ).o: $(UTILZ).h

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(EXECT).exe
```

So to build the object files first I run the following code in order to convert all the *.cpp files into object files with the same name (IE dbApi.cpp gets compiled into a dbApi.o object file):

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
```

and picks them from the header file. Then with that the default `all` , each object file I expect to be present gets added to the final compilation into an executable:

```
all: $(DBAPI).o $(TESTR).o $(UTILZ).o
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXECT).exe $^ $(LFLAGS)
```

Which should finally allow for program execution, in my case `./examiner.exe`.  There is some redundancy in my make file but it is relatively short and straight forward to follow.  Hopefully that helps leads you to a more concrete answer. Let me know.

~X

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're making an Operating System, because you mentioned qemu.

You should have sqlite file inside your project to call it or just making a new data storage file. Because you will need to call it inside makefile: [How do you actually use a C library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749079/how-do-you-actually-use-a-c-library)